# How to add event onClick in noty for notifications in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

I just want to go to a URL in my noty object is clicked (not when it's closed, only when the user clicks the notification). I tried this:

```
var n = noty({
    text: 'Nuevo Comentario: <br>' + data.contenido + ' de ' + data.usuario,
    layout: 'bottomRight',
    type: 'information',
    timeout: 3500,
    callback: { onClose: function() { /* Go to the URL i want to go */ }},
    animation: {
        open: {height: 'toggle'}, // jQuery animate function property object
        close: {height: 'toggle'}, // jQuery animate function property object
        easing: 'swing', // easing
        speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
    }
});
```

but the event is triggered even when it closes by itself. How can I check for when the user clicks on the notification?

Comment: I don't see any `onClick` callback provided by noty in the official docs. Did you try a simple `.click()` on a notification element? This will trigger standard `onClose`, sure, but it will also react to whatever you do in `.click()`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this hack and it work fine

```
           new Noty({
                layout: 'bottomRight',
                text: '<h6 onclick="clickOfDT()">_your text</h6>',
                type: 'warning',
                closeWith: ['button']
            }).show();

            clickOfDT=()=>{
                // HERE YOU GOT THE EVENT
            };
```